# Using Forms authentication cross domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, forms-authentication

here is our problem..
We have built an **MVC Web-api** that uses **Forms authentication** with cookies to handle sessions.
When we use our front-end webpage on the same domain (localhost or web-server) as the web-api, all works fine. (We use JQuery $.get and $.post to communicate with the web-api).

Though the front-end is in the future supposed to be a standalone html5 app, not located on the same domain as the web-api. 
This isn't working unfortunately.

The web-api does return an authentication cookie to the client, BUT the cookie isn't brought back to the web-api when the front-end sends it's requests.
When both web-api and front-end are on the same domain, the cookie is automatically sent with the request.

We've tried setting 
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and "Access-Control-Allow-Authentication: true" in the web-api webconfig file.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am in a similar situation but my client app in a HTML5 based phonegap application that runs on mobile browser containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a single-sign-on(SSO) feature.

Browser will only cookies to the same domain, that is the reason why it was not working when applications are located on different domains.

There a nice article in CodeProject on implementing SSO in ASP.NET - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic it applies to ASP.Net MVC too.

Comment: That is a great article!